# Comparing memory buffers

Tags: database, delphi, hash

I am working with Delphi and an in house ISAM database.

I have a function that returns the records from a table into a buffer of type pointer, one record at a time.  I am trying to group the records together as they are read in from the table.

At the moment it goes like this:

Read record from disk
If the the record is not in the record group list then add it to the list
otherwise discard it.

The function basically compares the record with all other records currently in the list until it either finds a match or reaches the end of the list.

I was using CompareMem to compare the record with the records in the list but this was slow.  I found a hashing function that can take a pointer instead of a string and that seems to work ok.

A record is made up of a number of fields of different data types (strings, integers, floats, booleans, etc).

Using the hash function is a bit faster and requires less memory as I now only need to store the hash value instead of a copy of the record.

I am sure there is a better way to do this.  Could someone please give me some suggestions about how to do this properly?.  I think hashing is the way to go and the hashing function I am using is ok but not very fast, perhapes someone could recommend a hash function?.

The data is accounting records, customer information, stock records, basically anything you would find in a typical accounting application's database.

Thank you

Comment: Likely you could optimize reading from disk by using larger buffers but ultimately you should use a profiler to narrow down where exactly you are spending your time.

Comment: As for hashing functions go, my first option would be to try SHA-1 or an MD5 hash. You could try to be clever and compute two hashes. One one a subset of the data and another one for the entire record. For most of your searches, computing the "fast" hash could be enough to determine that the records are not equal so you can move on to the next.

Comment: @Lieven Cryptographic-level SHA-1 or MD5 are not meant to be used for such comparison of multiple values. Their purpose is to check for data integrity. See my answer.

Comment: @Arnoud - I have and I learned a lot from it. See my comment :)

Comment: Have you considered adjusting your SQL so that it only returns distinct results? Then you don't have to remove duplicates yourself.

Comment: @Rob +1 This is indeed the first approach to attempt. The DB engine will do it better than you may do on client side (if you make a proper use of index and table structure), and you'll save bandwidth.

Comment: Yes you are correct that a DB engine would do a better job. Sorry I should have been more specific about what I am doing. I am implementing group by in a sql engine. The database is an ISAM DB from the 1980's so did not originally support sql. A developer some time ago wrote a basic client side sql engine with only select and join support. I have been given the job of extending it to support aggregates, group by, having and union. I have finished implementing all of these features but I am concerned about the performance of the group by. When collecting records I need a faster was to compare.

Comment: I have considered using a profiler, I have a licence for AQTime so i'll probably try that after I'm sure I am doing doing the compare for the group by as fast as possible.

Comment: @no spoon Did you take a look of the SQLite3 [virtual table](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) mechanism? It is able to use the SQL engine of SQLite3 ([proven and very complete](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) for such a small library) with any data back-end. We use it for instance in our mORMot framework to have SQL unified access to any data (even any remote DB). We wrote some [classes to work with Virtual Tables](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/05/14/Virtual-Tables-in-the-SQLite3-framework). May worth taking a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Searching using a hash function**

Here is how you may implement the hashing function in your search:

- Each record has its own hashed value available - should be stored within the database to save time: you won't have to compute it every time;
- To find if a record is already existing, compute its hashed value, then compare this hash with the hash list - on match, use CompareMem to be sure (collisions may occur, since no hash function is perfect).

You have two ways of comparing the new record hash to the hash list:

- The brute force just loop through all hashes, and compare them - faster than CompareMem, but will be O(n), that is will become slower when you add records;
- Use a hash lookup-table instead of a list of hashes - this lookup table size is usually a power of two, greater than the main hash list.

The hash lookup-table is the best option, IMHO. This is how Generics.Collections unit implement this in modern Delphi. Use it if you can.

For a variant using plain `record` content (including strings and nested dynamic arrays), you can take a look at our `TDynArrayHashed` wrapper.

In this case, the lookup table is just an array containing the 32 bit unsigned hash value and the index of the element in the array:

```
  TSynHash = record
    Hash: cardinal;
    Index: cardinal;
  end;

  TSynHashDynArray = array of TSynHash;
```

Here is for instance how the hash table lookup is populated from scratch:

```
procedure TDynArrayHashed.ReHash;
var i, n, PO2, ndx: integer;
    P: PAnsiChar;
    aHashCode: cardinal;
begin
  // find nearest power of two for new fHashs[] size
  SetLength(fHashs,0); // any previous hash is invalid
  n := Capacity+1; // use Capacity instead of Count for faster process 
  PO2 := 256;
  while PO2<n do
    PO2 := PO2 shl 1;
  SetLength(fHashs,PO2);
  // hash all dynamic array values
  P := Value^;
  for i := 0 to Count-1 do begin
    aHashCode := HashOne(P^);
    ndx := HashFind(aHashCode,P^);
    if ndx<0 then
      // >=0 -> already found -> not necessary to add duplicated hash
      with fHashs[-ndx-1] do begin
        Hash := aHashCode;
        Index := i;
      end;
    inc(P,ElemSize);
  end;
end;
```

Here is how an item is searched inside the hash lookup table:

```
function TDynArrayHashed.HashFind(aHashCode: cardinal; const Elem): integer;
var n, first: integer;
    looped: boolean;
begin
  looped := false;
  n := length(fHashs);
  result := (aHashCode-1) and (n-1); // fHashs[] has a power of 2 length
  first := result;
  repeat
    with fHashs[result] do
    if Hash=aHashCode then begin
      if ElemEquals(PAnsiChar(Value^)[Index*ElemSize],Elem) then begin
        result := Index;
        exit; // found -> returns index in dynamic array
      end;
    end else
    if Hash=0 then begin
      result := -(result+1);
      exit; // not found -> returns void index in fHashs[] as negative
    end;
    // hash colision -> search next item
    inc(result);
    if result=n then
      // reached the end -> search once from fHash[0] to fHash[first-1]
      if looped then
        Break else begin
        result := 0;
        n := first;
        looped := true;
      end;
  until false;
  raise Exception.Create('HashFind'); // we should never reach here
  result := -1; // mark not found
end;
```

It calls `ElemEquals` to compare in-deep the record content, in case of hash collision (may always happen). This function use Delphi RTTI to handle nested strings and (dynamic) arrays  in the record content. You can use `CompareMem` here if your record is just a binary buffer.

**2. The hash function**

About the hash function to be used, there are several around. If you need a hash lookup table, you won't need cryptographic-level hash functions (like SHA-1, MD5 or SHA-256) since you'll make a modulo according to the hash lookup table size, and those functions are much slower than the following one.

A simple one returning a cardinal will do the trick - the only issue in this regard is to avoid most collisions. Faster is Adler32 (or our Hash32), but you can use the classic but still fast Kernighan & Ritchie hash function, or a crc32 (it should be available in your code if you use zip for instance).

Here are some code returning a cardinal value, from our Open Source libraries. Each version has an optimized assembler function, and a 'pure pascal' version, perfect for ARM or 64 bit.

**Kernighan & Ritchie hash function**

```
function kr32(crc: cardinal; buf: PAnsiChar; len: cardinal): cardinal;
{$ifdef PUREPASCAL}
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to len-1 do
    crc := ord(buf[i])+crc*31;
  result := crc;
end;
{$else}
asm // eax=crc, edx=buf, ecx=len
    or ecx,ecx
    push edi
    push esi
    push ebx
    push ebp
    jz @z
    cmp ecx,4
    jb @s
@8: mov ebx,[edx] // unrolled version reading per DWORD
    lea edx,edx+4
    mov esi,eax
    movzx edi,bl
    movzx ebp,bh
    shr ebx,16
    shl eax,5
    sub eax,esi
    lea eax,eax+edi
    mov esi,eax
    shl eax,5
    sub eax,esi
    lea esi,eax+ebp
    lea eax,eax+ebp
    movzx edi,bl
    movzx ebx,bh
    shl eax,5
    sub eax,esi
    lea ebp,eax+edi
    lea eax,eax+edi
    shl eax,5
    sub eax,ebp
    cmp ecx,8
    lea eax,eax+ebx
    lea ecx,ecx-4
    jae @8
    or ecx,ecx
    jz @z
@s: mov esi,eax
@1: shl eax,5
    movzx ebx,byte ptr [edx]
    lea edx,edx+1
    sub eax,esi
    dec ecx
    lea esi,eax+ebx
    lea eax,eax+ebx
    jnz @1
@z: pop ebp
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi
end;
{$endif}
```

**Hash32 (modified adler32 function)**

```
function Hash32(Data: pointer; Len: integer): cardinal;
{$ifdef PUREPASCAL} // this code is quite as fast as the optimized asm below
function SubHash(P: PCardinalArray; L: integer): cardinal;
{$ifdef HASINLINE}inline;{$endif}
var s1,s2: cardinal;
    i: PtrInt;
const Mask: array[0..3] of cardinal = (0,$ff,$ffff,$ffffff);
begin
  if P<>nil then begin
    s1 := 0;
    s2 := 0;
    for i := 1 to L shr 4 do begin // 16 bytes (4 DWORD) by loop - aligned read
      inc(s1,P^[0]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[1]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[2]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[3]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(PtrUInt(P),16);
    end;
    for i := 1 to (L shr 2)and 3 do begin // 4 bytes (DWORD) by loop
      inc(s1,P^[0]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(PtrUInt(P),4);
    end;
    inc(s1,P^[0] and Mask[L and 3]);      // remaining 0..3 bytes
    inc(s2,s1);
    result := s1 xor (s2 shl 16);
  end else
    result := 0;
end;
begin // use a sub function for better code generation under Delphi
  result := SubHash(Data,Len);
end;
{$else}
asm // our simple and efficient algorithm (ADLER-32 based) is:
    //   while(data) do { s1 := s1+DWORD(data); s2 := s2+s1; }
    //   return (s1 xor (s2 shl 16));
    // this asm code is very optimized for modern pipelined CPU
    or eax,eax
    push ebx
    jz @z
    mov ecx,edx     // ecx = length(Data)
    mov edx,eax     // edx = Data
    xor eax,eax     // eax = s1 = 0
    xor ebx,ebx     // ebx = s2 = 0
    push ecx
    shr ecx,2
    jz @n
    push ecx
    shr ecx,2
    jz @m
    nop; nop
@16:add eax,[edx]   // 16 bytes (4 DWORD) by loop - aligned read
    add ebx,eax
    add eax,[edx+4] // both 'add' are pipelined: every DWORD is processed at once
    add ebx,eax
    add eax,[edx+8]
    add ebx,eax
    add eax,[edx+12]
    add ebx,eax
    dec ecx
    lea edx,edx+16
    jnz @16
@m: pop ecx
    and ecx,3
    jz @n
    nop
@4: add eax,[edx]  // 4 bytes (DWORD) by loop
    add ebx,eax
    dec ecx
    lea edx,edx+4
    jnz @4
@n: pop ecx
    mov edx,[edx] // read last DWORD value
    and ecx,3     // remaining 0..3 bytes
    and edx,dword ptr [@Mask+ecx*4] // trim to DWORD value to 0..3 bytes
    add eax,edx
    add ebx,eax
    shl ebx,16
    xor eax,ebx  // return (s1 xor (s2 shl 16))
@z: pop ebx
    ret
    nop; nop // align @Mask
@Mask: dd 0,$ff,$ffff,$ffffff // to get only relevant byte information
end;
{$endif}
```

**crc32 function**

```
{$define BYFOUR}
// if defined, the crc32 hashing is performed using 8 tables, for better
// CPU pipelining and faster execution

var
  // tables content is created from code in initialization section below
  // (save 8 KB of code size from standard crc32.obj, with no speed penalty)
  crc32tab: array[0..{$ifdef BYFOUR}7{$else}0{$endif},byte] of cardinal;

function crc32(crc: cardinal; buf: PAnsiChar; len: cardinal): cardinal;
// adapted from fast Aleksandr Sharahov version
asm
{$ifdef BYFOUR}
  test edx, edx
  jz   @ret
  neg  ecx
  jz   @ret
  not eax
  push ebx
@head:
  test dl, 3
  jz   @bodyinit
  movzx ebx, byte [edx]
  inc  edx
  xor  bl, al
  shr  eax, 8
  xor  eax,dword ptr [ebx*4 + crc32tab]
  inc  ecx
  jnz  @head
  pop  ebx
  not eax
@ret:
  ret
@bodyinit:
  sub  edx, ecx
  add  ecx, 8
  jg   @bodydone
  push esi
  push edi
  mov  edi, edx
  mov  edx, eax
@bodyloop:
  mov ebx, [edi + ecx - 4]
  xor edx, [edi + ecx - 8]
  movzx esi, bl
  mov eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*3]
  movzx esi, bh
  xor eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*2]
  shr ebx, 16
  movzx esi, bl
  xor eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*1]
  movzx esi, bh
  xor eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*0]
  movzx esi, dl
  xor eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*7]
  movzx esi, dh
  xor eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*6]
  shr edx, 16
  movzx esi, dl
  xor eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*5]
  movzx esi, dh
  xor eax,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*4]
  add ecx, 8
  jg  @done
  mov ebx, [edi + ecx - 4]
  xor eax, [edi + ecx - 8]
  movzx esi, bl
  mov edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*3]
  movzx esi, bh
  xor edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*2]
  shr ebx, 16
  movzx esi, bl
  xor edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*1]
  movzx esi, bh
  xor edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*0]
  movzx esi, al
  xor edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*7]
  movzx esi, ah
  xor edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*6]
  shr eax, 16
  movzx esi, al
  xor edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*5]
  movzx esi, ah
  xor edx,dword ptr [esi*4 + crc32tab + 1024*4]
  add ecx, 8
  jle @bodyloop
  mov eax, edx
@done:
  mov edx, edi
  pop edi
  pop esi
@bodydone:
  sub ecx, 8
  jl @tail
  pop ebx
  not eax
  ret
@tail:
  movzx ebx, byte [edx + ecx]
  xor bl,al
  shr eax,8
  xor eax,dword ptr [ebx*4 + crc32tab]
  inc ecx
  jnz @tail
  pop ebx
  not eax
{$else}
  test edx, edx
  jz @ret
  neg ecx
  jz @ret
  not eax
  sub edx,ecx
  push ebx
@next:
  movzx ebx, byte [edx + ecx]
  xor bl, al
  shr eax, 8
  xor eax, [ebx*4 + crc32tab]
  add ecx, 1
  jnz @next
  pop ebx
  not eax
@ret:
{$endif BYFOUR}
end;

and the associated code to create the tables


procedure InitCrc32Tab;
var i,n: integer;
    crc: cardinal;
begin // this code size is only 105 bytes, generating 8 KB table content  
  for i := 0 to 255 do begin
    crc := i;
    for n := 1 to 8 do
      if (crc and 1)<>0 then
        // $edb88320 from polynomial p=(0,1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,16,22,23,26)
        crc := (crc shr 1) xor $edb88320 else
        crc := crc shr 1;
    crc32tab[0,i] := crc;
  end;
{$ifdef BYFOUR}
  for i := 0 to 255 do begin
    crc := crc32tab[0,i];
    for n := 1 to 7 do begin
      crc := (crc shr 8) xor crc32tab[0,byte(crc)];
      crc32tab[n,i] := crc;
    end;
  end;
{$endif}
end;
```

With the BYFOUR define, this crc32 is very fast and has less collision than Hash32 or KR32.

For a comparison across hash functions see [this great article](http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions).

For the source code, see [our source code repository](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas).

Comment: +1 I assumed a hash-lookup table was already used. Rereading, I think your are right OP is using the "brute force" search. Great pointers on the speed for none cryptographic hashes, I really had no idea, thx.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I am using Delphi 2006 I need to a find my own hashing functions.  Hash32 looks pretty good.

Comment: I've implemented a hash table with collision detection.  It is much faster now.  Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The "better way to do this" is to avoid the problem in the first place. Modify your SQL so it will only return distinct records, and then you don't have to worry about post-processing to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that (unless you are using ShortString) CompareMem will not find duplicate records because the characters of the strings are not stored in the record/class directly, instead they are pointers. A hashing function that simply computes a hash based on the bytes will have the same problem.

So to make a hash you will need to use the bytes of all simple value types (integer, floats, boolean etc) and have a special case for strings that take the bytes that the string points to. For faster calculations you can simplify it by using something like the first few characters combined with the last, since you must take care of hash-collisions anyway.

If you are using Delphi 2009 or later there is a hashing function in the Generics.Defaults-unit. You can also try the Dictionary-class in Generics.Collections that use this algorithm,

Comment: based on OP's explanation, I assume a record is one contiguous block of memory when retrieved from the database. A hashing solution would work in this case.

Comment: @Lieven: Reading the question again I think you are probably right. My recommendation about the generics-units stands.

Comment: About record with nested strings or dynamic arrays (for instance), you are right. But you can use the RTTI to create a hash or compare the content of the record, with nested fields content. It's what our `TDynArray` does.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is MD5 – it is very fast. There are some MD5 implementations, particularly in OpenSSL, written in assembly, that are surprisingly fast. The implementation for 32-bit or 64-bit Intel processors have performance about or slightly less than 5 CPU cycles per byte (on processors with Skylake microarchitecture). It was about the same performance as for CRC-32 before Slicing-by-8 was invented for CRC32. Then CRC32 is implemented as Slicing-by-8, it is about 1.20 CPU cycles per byte on above processors.

Although MD5 is no longer considered a strong cryptographic hash function because of collisions, on practice you won't get any collisions for your application. The benefit of MD5 is that it has very small digest size comparing to other hash functions, so you won't waste space.

If you have a modern CPU that has a hardware implementation of SHA-1, then use SHA-1 instead. There are the following instructions: SHA1RNDS4, SHA1NEXTE, SHA1MSG1, SHA1MSG2, introduced on Intel Goldmont microarchitecture, and AMD Ryzen.

Alternatively, if your processor has ASE-NI support, you can calculate digests using AES. Just encrypt your messages with AES-CBC. Don't forget to add proper padding according to CMS rules before encryption. Use a constant key and a constant IV (initialization vector), but just make sure that they contain truly random bits (this requirement is particularly strong for the key, not for the IV). So the last encrypted block (128 bits) will be your digest. AES is very fast if your processor supports AES-NI.

Alternatively, you can use CRC-32 if your processor can accelerate it (the CRC32 instruction) or if you use Slicing-By-8 CRC implementation. But CRC-32 may only be good if you have small number or messages and small message sizes. I cannot tell you exact figures – it depends on the amount of risk that you are willing to take.

Comment: MD5 is not very fast. It was actually originally designed to be slow to prevent fast calculation of checksums for finding collisions. CRC32 is much faster, even if the processor does not support it directly.

Comment: @dummzeuch I have specified that MD5 is about 5 CPU cycles per byte while CRC32 before Slicing-8 is about the same while with Slicing-8 is 1,2 CPU cycles per byte. Have you seen the figures?